# Graphite divideSeries wrong result

Tags: division, grafana, graphite

I'm using Grafana and Graphite to draw a percentage of "succes" rate in our dashboard:

I can draw the success rate
[image: success]

I can metric the total
[image: total]

But when I try to get the percentage, it doesn't seem to do the division as I was taught in school :)
[image: divideSeries]
[image: percent]
Am I doing something wrong?

(I tried with both the *current* value of the series and the *average*)

Following the suggestion of @AussieDan the situation get more weird:

Drawing all the three series, I can see just 2:
[image: All over time]

Removing the *total* from the graph the values are consistent...
[image: success/ratio over time]

But when I leave just the ratio of the two:
[image: ratio]

Using *asPercent*:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the graph of the underlying series it's tough to say what exactly is going on.  If you can plot those 4 queries on a standard graph panel it might help to figure out what's happening.

The graph images help somewhat, they do show that `asPercent` and `divideSeries` are internally consistent, with the `asPercent` values being 100x the `divideSeries` values which is what we expect.

Can you grab 2 more screenshots with just `success` and just `total` so we can see what's going on there?  I'm not sure I trust the screenshot where `divideSeries` doesn't show up despite being marked visible.

Comment: I've added the graphs to the post...the situation is getting more weird :|

Comment: @rascio I updated the answer, we're getting somewhere but need a little more info